# Bluegiga set as a receiver with iPhone Peripheral

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, gatt, bluegiga

I have a BLE dongle named Bluegiga (BLED112).

[Bluegiga USB dongle](https://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/products/bled112-bluetooth-smart-dongle/)

By using the BLEGUI I can see my bluetooth GATT profile Service UUID and characteristic UUID.
While press the connect button it shows connected but, I am sending data from iPhone It is not received in BLEUI. The central (Bluegiga) is running in a windows PC.

If anyone used the Bluegiga dongle, please help me to correct the same for a data transfer from iPhone to the target.

Comment: I have used the BLED112 dongle to receive data on the computer, and it works fine. Are you sure you are writing into and looking into the appropriate characteristics?

Comment: Yes, My characteristics are listed in Bluegiga UI and try to conneect with service it shows connected and after sometime it is disconnected automatically. After connected I tried to send string from phone not received in the Blugiga UI. (not flashed the Bluegiga dongle).

Comment: The automatic disconnect can be a different issue (probably, Link Supervision Timeout) altogether.

Comment: Is it need to flash the dongle for communication ?

Comment: Is it need to change any xml files in the sdk installation path ?

Comment: No, that isn't needed either. Just give an hour or so to demonstrate the same in office today. I'll probably answer the question by 5 pm (IST)

Comment: @WedaPashi: Do you got the solution.